# JAVA Thread Concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using ExecutorService to launch multiple threads.

- Thread A
- Thread B
- Thread C
  and
- Thread D
- ....
- ....
  Thread N

All thread started concurrently.
I am using a ConcurrentHashMap to store result of Thread A , Thread B , Thread C which can be used by Thread D in future.

Now it may happen that Thread A is still under execution when Thread D is looking for the output from Thread A.

This is applicable for Thread C which may be dependent on output of Thread D

Or Thread N which may be dependent on output of any of threads like Thread N-1 , or Thread N- 4 etc ...

What can be the best approach to handle this situation or to make thread A wait until other threads are ready with there output

Comment: I assume you want Thread D to wait for the output given Thread A is producing the output.

Comment: Personally, I'd probably launch `D` after `A` has completed as part of `A`'s work.  But, if I recall correctly, `Future#get` is blocking...

Comment: I agree with MadProgrammer, put D on sleep and have A notify it is a perfectly valid way to about this.

Comment: Yes, have Thread D wait till A has fully completed its execution.

Comment: @iWumbo In that case Thread A could be renamed D and do the work D does after it has finished.

Comment: What is in the hashmap?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having three tasks producing results which are queued into the same Executor or another executor.  This way Thread D only does work when there is something to do.

A better option might be for Thread A to process its own work immediately (and the same for Thread B & C) in which case you don't need Thread D.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use join. Joining threads after starting will effectively make your program run in a liniear fashion. Thread A runs, Then B, then C then D will look for the results of the first 3 threads once thread C has finished.

Comment: If you're going to do that, why not simply call functions A(), B(), C(), and D() sequentially and completely avoid threads?

Comment: I agree, but you may wish for more threads to do similar tasks in the future whilst still have D collect results.